# How can I check if a telephone number exist programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I want to do an Android App that check if a number exist or not. In particular I was thinking of calling the number to check and if it ring it means that exist, otherwise it does not.

At the moment I can read the state "IDLE" and "OFFHOOK" but not  the state "CALL_STATE_RINGING" that as far as I understood trigger only for received call.

How can I understand when it is ringing and when the number is not valid?

Note: The calling approach is just an idea but I could accept others solutions if they are effective.

My code at the moment:

Listener:

```
public class EndCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {
private String TAG = "CALL_AUTOMATICALLY_LISTENER";


@Override
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
        // TODO
        Log.i(TAG, "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
    }
    if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
        Log.i(TAG, "OFFHOOK");
    }
    if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
        Log.i(TAG, "IDLE");
    }
}
}



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String TAG = "CALL_AUTOMATICALLY";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        askPermission();
    }

    private void askPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},0);
    }

    public void startCall(View view) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                String number = "+39555555555"; // fake number
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
                // Activate listener
                EndCallListener callListener = new EndCallListener();
                TelephonyManager mTM = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                if (mTM != null) mTM.listen(callListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
                else Log.d(TAG, "TelephonyManager null");
                // start call
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                askPermission();
            }
        }
    }

    public void startCallNotExisting(View view) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                String number = "+39456464564545555565656565";
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
                // Activate listener
                EndCallListener callListener = new EndCallListener();
                TelephonyManager mTM = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                if (mTM != null) mTM.listen(callListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
                else Log.d(TAG, "TelephonyManager null");
                // start call
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                askPermission();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to know if a number exists?

Comment: @lugiorgi: it is one functionality required

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check phone number regex instead of calling them.place this method in your helper or activity or fragment class

```
public static boolean validateMobile(String mobile) {
    if (mobile.matches("^[+]?[0-9]{10,13}$")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And use it like

```
if(Helper.validateMobile(mobile){
//mobile is valid
}else{
//mobile is not valid}
```

also this regex can be different if you target one specific country.for example i use below regex for iran phone numbers

```
(\\+98|0)?9\\d{9}
```

Comment: In this way that number could be valid but may not exist. Thanks anyway for your answer.

Comment: In your case there is a paid plan in below website which can check this using api call.